# ld: library not found for -lAppAuth

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, appauth

Facing this error on building a react-native project. I did not include this package on my own, but I think it came along Firebase.
Have done all usual remedies like uninstall-re-install node modules, pod installs, pod updates but still no luck.
Any leads appreciated.

Error log as attatched.
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqYW4.png)

Comment: need more details of the error.  use command to get details stacktrace.
succh as  ./gradlew assembleDebug --info

Comment: whether issue got fixed or not

Answer (score 1):

Add `${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppAuth` to `Library Search Paths`

[image]

Comment: i have this present and yet i am throwing the same error